# Is it possible to pass a NULL into an SQL Server Stored Procedure from Typescript

Tags: sql-server, typescript, vue.js

I'm stuck in a situation where i have to pass a value as Null to a uniqueidentifier variable i declared in a stored procedure.
The problem is that i have to pass an empty string to the variable, where it generates an error **"Cannot convert varchar to uniqueidentifier"**. From eecuting the procedure in SQL serve, all works well, but typescript generates the above error...

**Here is the procedure code executed:**

```
USE [CMS_ONE]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PrAdmissionReports]
        @session = '82c16d40-56ba-4e5a-b6f4-8f3767fc48fa',
        @campus = '0EF13205-3150-43F3-A37A-CDE57BFD544E',
        @program = '929A0FCD-81C8-44D3-AC56-020E7C0AA2B2',
        @fromDate = '2018-07-02',
        @toDate = '2018-07-27'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I'm passing @program as ProgramDetailID = null to the procedure, but it keeps returning the error.

This is how i pass the values from the front:

```
this.sessionID +
  "," +
  this.campusID +
  "," +
  this.programDetailID +
  "," +
  this.fromDate +
  "," +
  this.toDate
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you passing empty string or NULL ? where is the single quote ?

Comment: I'm passing an empty string...but recently i tried to set ProgramDetailID = null, and tried passing it...but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sanity's sake I'm assuming you're using a javascript based backend here and not just calling directly into your database from the frontend because that would be dangerous.

You're concatenating an empty string there. you could use something like:

```
this.someField ? this.someField : 'NULL'
```

or

```
this.someField ?? 'NULL'
```

a better, safer way would be to parameterize your queries.